# Base virtual host config + domain specific customizations

Tags: apache, ssl

So I have two domains that both point to the same IP address, and right now I have a separate `<VirtualHost>` entry for each, using named virtual hosts.

The reason I've done this is so i can use different SSL certs for each domain (example here: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)

This is all fine, but I have about 100 other lines in each `<VirtualHost>` that are will be exactly the same regardless of domain, with only the SSL info being different.

Is it possible to have a "base" config (the 100 similar lines), but add a few custom tweaks for each named virtual host? (different SSL certs in this case)?

Comment: Not your question, but if there is no problem to show them together you could create a single X.509 certificate with both names in it.

Comment: Depending on what you have in these "100 lines" you can put them outside of any `VirtualHost` and they would then apply to all `VirtualHost`.  Double check the Apache documentation that will tell you in which scope each directive can appear or not.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yeah, not allowed to combined them in this case. Didnt even think about sticking them outside the virtual host.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know you could stick anything outside of `VirtualHost`, but that ended up working for me (I also needed `RewriteOptions Inherit` to make it work nicely but that is only for my specific case...)